# How do I show multiple boxplots showing distribution using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to get a graph like this to show boxplot distributions for each age group:

[image: Boxplots]

But instead my plot looks like this:
[image: Not boxplots]

How can I get the boxplots to show rather than the points? Why is my Y axis non numeric?

My data looks like this:
[image: My data]

And here's the plot code I am trying:

```
p2 <- ggplot(data = popSample, aes(x = AGEGRP, y = TOT_POP)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = AGEGRP)) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  theme_light()
p2
```

Thank you for helping someone who is learning,

Comment: Because your data is not linear or skewed. You need to transform your data using `log10` or `BoxCox` transformation.

Comment: Isn't it the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60132869/how-can-i-plot-multiple-box-plots-by-a-factor-on-a-single-ggplot